# duplicated/stale user directory when changing admin user with local account on windows

Tags: windows-11, user-accounts

After installing Windows 11 I was forced to use a microsoft account.

I temporary created one called `Foo`.

I didn't want that option, so I later created a new local admin account `Bar`, and deleted the old one.

Something got messed up in the process: the user directory of the old account `Foo` is still existing and many application recognize it as the user dir of the new only user `Bar`.

For example if I login using user `Bar` (now the only user) and open Documents or Downloads folder from explorer, I end up in c:\Users\Foo. Firefox downloads still end up there.

Other applications like Visual Studio, use the new folder instead: c:\Users\Bar.

I am not fussy about the name, as long as it's consistent.

Any idea how to fix this?

Comment: Associated the account with a Microsoft Account, then immediately disconnect the Microsoft Account, in doing so you will be prompted for the name of the local user account.